# fonts not applying for ionic/phonegap application

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework

i am trying to apply the font family for ionic based app. It is applying in desktop browser(chrome) but not applying in Android device.

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'VAG Round';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 200;
      src: local('VAG Round'), local('VAGRound'), url('../lib/ionic/fonts/VAG Round.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
body{
  font-family: 'VAG Round';
}
```

I also copied the font file inside the, `lib/ionic/fonts` directory but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at the element's css with [chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging)?

Comment: yes..it is applied as expected

Comment: Hmm okay, what is the android version of the device you're testing with?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [Content Security Policy](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy) issue or a [whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html) issue. To further track down the problem: add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

to your `index.html`
and

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```

to your `config.xml`

also look [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-font-usage/4270/11) if putting it in the www directory might help you or other methods explained in the thread. hope that any of the answers will solve your problem